# Equal Heights of Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I'm doing is trying to make a certain class of objects all equal, but make it useful and simplistic enough be re-purposed throughout various documents.

Everything look valid and legit to me, but something is messing up.

```
function cardHeights(divGroup) {
console.log("This is running");
divGroup.each(function (e) {
    var current = $(this),
        curTallest = 0;

    if (current.height() > curTallest) {
        curTallest = current.height();
        console.log(curTallest);
    }

    divGroup.height(curTallest);
});
}
```

Then I use this to call the function to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    cardHeights('.card');
    $(window).on('resize', cardHeights('.card')); 
});
```

Here is a codepen where I got it to work, but I can't get it to work on an actual site.  Which is weird to me.  It gives an error that it is not a defined function.

*TypeError: e.each is not a function*

http://codepen.io/ddavisgraphics/pen/ZYQxqq

Comment: You are resetting `curTallest` to zero upon each iteration. You may want to set this outside of your `each` loop. Also, only reset the `divGroup` height if `current.height() > curTallest`.

Comment: somthing messing up always gets me!

Comment: `cardHeights()` expects a jQuery object. You are passing it a string.

Comment: @showdev so I need to pass it like cardHeights($('.card'))?

Comment: Yes, or generate that object from the string inside your function, e.g. `var divGroupObject = $(divGroup)`. Either way.

Comment: Are you just trying to make the objects of equal widths and heights, maintaining an aspect ratio?

Comment: Even better would be to collect all the heights, find the max, and set all heights to the max one time only (rather than resetting heights every time a taller `.card` is found).

Comment: @Todd Just Equal Heights.  I don't care about ratio because all that is handled by the CSS.  But due to the nature of this template I can't rely on css to solve equal heights problem.

Comment: @showdev I'm open to the suggestion if you can get me started down that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reiterate my comments:

1. Resetting `curTallest` on each iteration will prevent finding the tallest element. Each element in the loop will be considered the tallest because `curTallest` is reset to zero each time.
2. You'll only need to reset the height of `divGroup` if `current.height() > currTallest`. Currently, you reset the heights upon each iteration, regardless of whether `currTallest` has changed.
3. `cardHeights()` expects a jQuery object. You are passing it a string. Either pass a jQuery object or convert the string to an object within the function.

That being said, my suggestion is to collect all heights, determine the maximum height from those values, and set all heights to the maximum height. This prevents needlessly setting heights multiple times.

Here's an example:

```js
$(function() {
  cardHeights('.card');
  $(window).on('resize', cardHeights('.card'));
});


function cardHeights(divGroup) {

  /* Initialize variables */
  var heights = [],
      $group = $(divGroup);

  /* Iterate through the selected elements, pushing their heights into an array */
  $group.each(function() {
    heights.push($(this).height());
  });

  /* Determine the maximum height in the array */
  var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heights);

  /* Set the height of all elements in the group to the maximum height */
  $group.height(maxHeight);

}
```

```css
div.card {
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">Test</div>
<div class="card">Test<br />Tester<br />Testing<br />Test-o-rama<br />Tallest!</div>
<div class="card">Test<br />Tester</div>
```

### Edit

If, for some reason, you don't want to use an array, you can use your original method of comparing each element's height to the maximum height:

```
function cardHeights(divGroup) {

  /* Initialize variables */
  var $group = $(divGroup),
      maxHeight=0,
      thisHeight=0;

  /* Iterate selected elements, reset maxHeight if the current height is taller */
  $group.each(function() {
    thisHeight=$(this).height();
    if (thisHeight>maxHeight) {maxHeight=thisHeight;}
  });

  /* Set the height of all elements in the group to the maximum height */
  $group.height(maxHeight);

}
```

Comment: This is a much better use of jQuery

Comment: Thanks I will work something up but I get what your saying.  Thank you both.  I never think of arrays on frontend jobs.

Answer (score 0):

`cardHeights('.card');` should be `cardHeights($('.card'));` because `divGroup` in `cardHeights(divGroup)` is supposed to be a jQuery object

Comment: This does solve the problem I'm having.  It won't let me check the answer yet, but I'm also going to listen to showdev suggestion to see if that is a better option. Thank you all for your help.